# Resource for scientific maps?

Tags: geography, mapping

I need an administrative division map of england for a motivation for some scientific workshop. I don't want to cite wikipedia for this. Sadly I can't find any official resources and I don't really know what sites are generally trusted or scientific.

Any tips? I hope this is the correct forum for this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually refer to two free of charge sources for administrative division maps:

- for Europe, as in your case (I hope they still hold the maps of UK even after Brexit...) you can use the official NUTS - Nomenclature of territorial units for statistics maps from EUROSTAT available [here](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/nuts/nuts-maps);
- EUROSTAT has also a regularly updated dataset of the official boundaries for the whole world [here](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/countries) (latest update 2020, but I don't remember how down to the finer statistical territorial units they get with this);
- DIVA GIS repository: administrative maps of every country in the world (not sure how updated this is), available [here](https://www.diva-gis.org/gdata).

I'm sure there will be more datasets like these, but these should fit your purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Most maps of Great Britain derive from the maps published by [Her Majesty's Ordnance Survey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey).  The official website is https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ and the [sales page](https://shop.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/apps/os-maps/) says that for £23.99 you can get a 1 year subscription to a digital app that gives you the ability to export in the [GPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format) digital format.

A crowd sourced version working on a map of the world is [The Open Street Map](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) Project.  This is equivalent to your rejected option of Wikipedia but I mention it for others that may land on this question.